# Split string by condition in Python

Tags: python

How can I split a string like this:

```
'-999-999-999-999-999-999-9992-999-999'
```

to

```
['-999-999-999-999-999-999-999', '2', '-999-999']
```

I tried to use `re.split()` and regex, but I don't understand what condition should I use to find e.g. `'-999'`?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you looking for 4 digits instead of 3? or the first number that has different digit within it? The question does not specify the criteria you want to split by.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you tried? And what went wrong?

Comment: @MyWork I got pandas dataframe values, so after I get list of this values, I join them: newdf = ''.join(newdf), and then I tried to get all my '-999' by Index in dataframe. But my cycle went wrong, because I got 21kk+ rows. After this I tried do smth like newdf = list(map(itemgetter(0), re.findall(r'((.)\2*)', newdf))), but I really dont understand how regex works.

Comment: @bokushi instead of trying to parse a bad design, fix your design. There are only bad answers to give you  because the scenario you've created is bad. It's like you're asking: "I converted everything to Mandarin for no good reason, how do I convert it back to English?" To be clear, the answer to your question is ~ Don't convert everything to "Mandarin" in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

With `re.split()`:

```
import re

s = '-999-999-999-999-999-999-9992-999-999'

print (re.split('(2)',s))
# You can use any number/char or (regex expression) instead of 2
```

Output:

```
['-999-999-999-999-999-999-999', '2', '-999-999']
```

You can keep the delimiter you split on using the syntax above.

Comment: Unfortunaly, I got not only '2'. I had a lot of numbers from 1 to 100 or maybe more and '-999' is something like NaN in my data (the program unloads in this format and I cant do anything with this)

Comment: just change 2 by whatever it works the same

Comment: @Manuel, my bad.

Comment: Because you want to keep the delimiter. So that s the way to do :)

Comment: @Synthase can I change '2' to np.arange(100) or something like that?

Comment: it has to be a regex. A np array is surely not a regex. So you need to make a regex from your array first. But that's an other question :)

Comment: thank You. So, I am going to try different ways to solve my issue.

Comment: You can ask a new question for this part, and think about accepting that one if that helped

Comment: @bokushi, can you try re.split('([^-9]+)',s)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the comments that I read, you are actually creating this scenario and you just shouldn't. Then you wouldn't have to solve it. However, there is a way to get the data you want. If you want to keep the `-999` you can do it as below.

```py
s = '-999-999-999-999-999-999-9992-999-999'

results = [n if n != '' else '-999' for n in s.split('-999')]
print(results) #['-999', '-999', '-999', '-999', '-999', '-999', '-999', '2', '-999', '-999']
```

If you don't want to keep the `-999` you can do it like this.

```
s = '-999-999-999-999-999-999-9992-999-999'

results = [n for n in s.split('-999') if n != '']
print(results) #['2']
```

And if you want to keep everything in tact ~ ie. literally only separating streams of `-999` from other items, you can do it like this.

```py
s = '-999-999-999-999-999-999-9992-999-999'

out    = ''
result = []
data   = s.split('-999')

for i, n in enumerate(data):
    if n == '':
        out = f'{out}-999'
    else:
        if len(out):
            result.append(out)
            out = ''
        result.append(n)
        
    if i == (len(data) - 1) and len(out):
        result.append(out)
        
print(result) #['-999-999-999-999-999-999-999', '2', '-999-999']
```